# How do I create multiple password generator based on user's input?

Tags: python, loops

So this is what I'm trying to do almost three hours. It only prints one password no matter what I try. I want it to generate number of passwords equal to user's input `password_number`
It's on another language, sorry.

```
import random
simboli = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', "'", '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', '[', ']', '^', '_', '`', '{', '|', '}', '~']

character_number = int(input('Izaberi duzinu lozinke (najbolje od 8 do 32)  '))
password_number = int(input('Koliko razlicitih lozinki hoces?  '))

password = ''

while password_number == broj_lozinki:
    for x in range(character_number):
        password = password + random.choice(simboli)
        if len(password) == character_number:
            print(password)
```

Comment: I think you want to assign `password = ''` at the top of the loop, otherwise you're continually adding random characters to the end of the same password, and `len(password) == character_number` will only be true once.

Answer (score 0):

You keep adding more characters on to the end of the existing password, so after you print out the first one, you end up with passwords that are too long and thus don't get printed.

To fix the issue, move the initialization of `password` into the outer loop.

```
for _ in range(password_number):    # the outer loop can be a for loop
    password = ""                   # initialize password to an empty string
    for _ in range(character_number):
        password += random.choice(simboli)   # build up the password
    print(password)     # no need for a length check, just print in the outer loop
```

I also make some additional changes, like making the outer loop us `for` rather than `while` (which the code you posted didn't manage properly), and moving the `print` call from the inner loop (guarded with an `if`) into the outer loop, where it will only run after the inner loop has finished.

You could further improve things by replacing the inner loop that manually builds up the password one character at  a time by a list comprehension inside a call to `str.join`: `"".join([random.choice(simboli) for _ in range(character_number)])`. Using the `join` method to combine a sequence of strings into a larger string is usually more efficient than repeatedly concatenating with `+`, though there is a special case for using `+=` that means you don't *always* get bad performance even from naive code (that was one other small change I made in the code above).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, you are trying to create a variable number of passwords where each password is of variable length.

The main issue that I see in your code is that you don't update anything once inside the `while` loop.

Below, we run through a loop n number of times where n is the number of passwords you want to generate. Then, we have a list comprehension that picks random characters x number of times where x is the character number.

```
from random import choice

character_num = int(input("Enter character number: "))
password_num = int(input("Enter password number: "))

passwords = []
for _ in range(password_num):
    pswd = [choice(simboli) for _ in range(character_num)]
    passwords.append("".join(pswd))
```

Output (`character_num = 20`, `password_num = 10`):

```py
[
    "o_1z#;=}'tTE_HXqy+Zq",
    "?u6$E|rS;_}MPO7-67jt",
    "SN2$l{jM(g&F3#DP!JMS",
    "Ts5%J/!A4@=:w-hc&?:#",
    "T}l,qR5oUHvO91(i}bI"",
    "g=4DwnPM!rM]:VBkbGQy",
    "/2+r1:K85-:oC.B87l~U",
    "]G1mRq8OER.?cR3e*5#@",
    "VU#AIH<;P_rc~E}y%YZ_",
    "TBcG&F=[BEbT0_p|Z50E"
]
```